# Localization of Resources

Tags: c#

I have a dataTable and a resx file with Name , Value , Comments as Columns.. I'm reading a resource with ResXResourceReader.. and assigning to grid.. I'm adding new values in the grid.. I want to reflect the new values in the resx file.. Can anyone help..After Looping and im writing to the corresponding resx!!! Whether it ll be overwriten???? If i do im getting IOException was Unhandled!!!!

Comment: Please show some code. If you want to add new entries in your resource file, open it in vs and add them manually, or if you want to do it in code, use a file writer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code of ResxCrunch (http://resxcrunch.com or http://resxcrunch.codeplex.com/).
The application edits .resx files in a grid and uses a DataTable as data source. I don't know for sure if it solves your problem, but it's worth a try.